# A partition problem

Tags: partitions

I want to find all partitions of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,40\}$ into disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that no subset of $B$ has a sum that is a member of $A$?

I have an algorithm for doing this although it is too slow for a set this size. Is anyone aware of an efficient method? Or does unavoidably reduce to a subset-sum problem?

Comment: There are going to be A LOT of valid partitions... The number of subsets of `Range[40]` is `Sum[Binomial[40, n], {n, 0, 40}]`, that is, 1 099 511 627 776. Fitting `a Exp[b x]` to the actual number of valid partitions of `Range[m]` from `m` 3 to 15 gives that the number of valid subsets for `Range[40]` should be ballpark $2 \times 10^7$. What will you be doing with them?

Comment: Thanks, Marius. I will evaluating a function for each valid partition. I've come up with a more efficient way of finding the valid partitions recursively. I haven't run it yet, but it shouldn't take the lifetime of the universe this time!

Comment: Then consider self-posting that solution so others (like me) can learn :) I'll compare your solution to mine and consider posting it.

Comment: I'll iron it out and then post - hopefully in the next day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do this recursively, by ensuring in each recursive call that the solutions produced satisfy the criterion in the OP. It suffices to consider $B$: $A$ can always be found by `Complement[Range[n], b]` if needed.

The recursive function is

```
rec[set_, totals_, ind_] := Block[{next, newset, newtotals},
  Sow[set];
  next = Complement[Range[ind, n], set];
  Do[
   newset = Union[set, {j}];
   newtotals = Select[Union[totals, totals + j], # <= n &];
   {newset, newtotals} = necessary[newset, newtotals];
   rec[newset, newtotals, j + 1]
   , {j, next}
   ]
  ]
```

The idea is that, starting from a given set `set` with known subset sums `totals`, the new subset sums that appear by adding a number `j` to `set` is simply `totals + j`, as long as we include the empty subset and its sum, 0. For instance, the set `{2, 5}` has subsets `{{}, {2}, {5}, {2,5}}` with sums `{0, 2, 5, 7}`. If we add 8 to this set, the new subsets are `{{8}, {2,8}, {5,8}, {2,5,8}}`, with sums `{8, 10, 13, 15}`, of course equal to `{0, 2, 5, 7} + 8`.

Now, to satisfy the criterion in the OP, we need to check that any number in `totals` in the range `Range[n]` is present in `set`. This is taken care of by the function `necessary`, that, after adding an "optional" value `j` to `set`, continues to add values until `newset` satisfies the criterion. The function is:

```
necessary[set_, totals_] := Block[{missing},
  missing = Complement[Rest@totals, set];
  If[Length@missing == 0, {set, totals},
   necessary @@
    Fold[
     Function[{settot, miss},
      {Union[settot[[1]], {miss}], 
       Select[Union[settot[[2]], settot[[2]] + miss], # <= n &]}],
     {set, totals}, missing]
   ]
  ]
```

Finally, the recursive code is called from a wrapper

```
validPartitions[range_] :=
 Block[{n = range},
  Reap[rec[{}, {0}, 1]][[2, 1]]
 ]
```

Testing:

```
AbsoluteTiming[MaxMemoryUsed[v40 = validPartitions[40];]]
```

> > {484.299998, 1 801 941 672}

```
Length[v40]
```

> > 11 347 437

Comment: Hi Marius. That is a great answer - similar but (much) cleaner than mine. Sorry that I hadn't had the time to type it up.